# IIS - https not working

Tags: ssl, iis, https, lets-encrypt

Hoping someone can help me with this...

I have got a simple html page hosted in IIS on an Amazon EC2 instance. Calls to http works (http://website.com/test.html) but https doesn't (https://website.com/test.html)

I have got a Let's Encrypt certificate installed in IIS and I have got a https binding in IIS using the certificate.

I have made sure that the firewall rule "World Wide Web Services (HTTPS Traffic-In)" is enabled and is allowing connections.

I have run "netstat -aon | findstr 0.0:443" on the server and that gives me:

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:443            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
```

I have restarted IIS and restarted the EC2 instance.

Is there anything that I should be checking?  Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you check the network interface that the virtual machine is using? Sometimes port 443 isn't open on the network interface, even if it's open on the virtual machine itself.

Comment: You only configured Windows Firewall on that machine, but AWS should have another firewall setting to expose port 443 for the public IP. Check its documentation please.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was bugging me for a long time! I had to expose port 443 from AWS Console too.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. I made it an answer and would appreciate if you could mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything is configured on your ec2 instance then make sure to check that the AWS network interface is open from the console too.

Sometimes port 443 isn't open on the network interface, even if it's open on the virtual machine itself.